# How to compute the fractional field of a quotient ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I want to compute the fractional field of a quotient ring.

For example, how to write $Frac(\mathbb Z[x,y]/(y^2 - mx))$ in an explicit way?

In general, if $D$ is an integral domain and $\frak{p}$ is a prime ideal, then is there any method to write $Frac(D/\frak{p})$ in an explict way?

This question is actually from the following example. I just want to show the induced morphism is birational.
[image]

Comment: An element of $\operatorname{Frac}(D/\mathfrak{p})$ is a fraction, whose nominator is a residue class of $D$ mod $\mathfrak{p}$ and whose denominator is a non-zero residue class of $D$ mod $\mathfrak{p}$. I don't think you should expect more explicitness in general.

Comment: In fact, I just need to show $\mathbb Z[x,y]/(y^2-mx)$ and $\mathbb Z[x,y]/(y^2-n^2mx)$, where $m$ is square free, have the same fractional field. Is there any way to show this without write down the explicit form of the fractional field?